# How to create critical section in nodejs multi-instance application in Kubernetes?

Tags: node.js, kubernetes, mean-stack, critical-section

I have a scenarios where an interval is running in nodejs for sending period mailers. Now this MEAN stack application has multiple instances in a Kubernetes deployment. What's happening is for all instances interval is running and same mailer is triggered for all the instances. I want that only single instance should trigger the mailer at a time. How to go about this? Never faced this scenario of multi-instance deployment of an application.

Comment: separate your mailer from the main application, then from your application make a call to your mailer service to send the mail.

Answer (score 0):

It would be good to run this periodic task as [kubernetes cronjob](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/). This may require you to refactor your application.

One possible solution could be to collect information where and what to sent into a message queue or database. For example, rabbitmq, redis or sql. Then periodically, the cronjob can send out all the emails and mark them as send or remove them from the *to sent* queue/database/collection.